# Racket: make-least-squares-point-smoother from simple-polynomial/fit does not work

Tags: racket

I try to use polynomial smoothing of data https://docs.racket-lang.org/simple-poly-manual/index.html. I use exactly the same example as this site:
`(define datasp (points->spline-evaluator data)) (define datasm (points->spline-evaluator ((make-least-squares-point-smoother 7 4 0) data)` The first spline works well but second gives error `make-least-squares-point-smoother: unbound identifier in: make-least-squares-point-smoother`. The `data` has 100 entries. I considered different values instead of 7 4 0 and have the same error. I'm newby in the racket, please explain to me what happens, why the example does not work.

Comment: It seems like a bug in simple-polynomial, where https://bitbucket.org/derend/simple-polynomial/src/master/simple-polynomial/fit.rkt didn't provide `make-least-squares-point-smoother`.
The definition is in https://bitbucket.org/derend/simple-polynomial/src/master/simple-polynomial/private/poly-smooth.rkt

Comment: It works well with a simple trick https://racket.discourse.group/t/make-least-squares-point-smoother-from-simple-polynomial-fit-does-not-work/559 .